# "Realtime" syncing of large numbers of log files to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large number of logfiles from a service that I need to regularly run analysis on via EMR/Hive. There are thousands of new files per day, and they can technically come out of order relative to the file name (e.g. a batch of files comes a week after the date in the file name).

I did an initial load of the files via Snowball, then set up a script that syncs the entire directory tree once per day using the 'aws s3 sync' cli command. This is good enough for now, but I will need a more realtime solution in the near future. The issue with this approach is that it takes a very long time, on the order of 30 minutes per day. And using a ton of bandwidth all at once! I assume this is because it needs to scan the entire directory tree to determine what files are new, then sends them all at once.

A realtime solution would be beneficial in 2 ways. One, I can get the analysis I need without waiting up to a day. Two, the network use would be lower and more spread out, instead of spiking once a day.

It's clear that 'aws s3 sync' isn't the right tool here. Has anyone dealt with a similar situation?

One potential solution could be:
Set up a service on the log-file side that continuously syncs (or aws s3 cp) new files based on the modified date. But wouldn't that need to scan the whole directory tree on the log server as well?

For reference, the log-file directory structure is like: 
/var/log/files/done/{year}/{month}/{day}/{source}-{hour}.txt

There is also a /var/log/files/processing/ directory for files being written to.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've used [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) as part of the overall ELK stack for this.  It seems to be very efficient and has a [plugin for S3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) too - you don't have to log to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a Lambda function triggered automatically as a new object is saved on your S3 bucket. Check [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) for details. The event passed to the Lambda function will contain the file name, allowing you to target only the new files in the syncing process.

If you'd like wait until you have, say 1,000 files, in order to sync in batch, you could use [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sqs/) and the following workflow (using 2 Lambda functions, 1 CloudWatch rule and 1 SQS queue):

1. S3 invokes Lambda whenever there's a new file to sync
2. Lambda stores the filename in SQS
3. CloudWatch triggers another Lambda function every X minutes/hours to check how many files are there in SQS for syncing. Once there's 1,000 or more, it retrieves those filenames and run the syncing process.

Keep in mind that Lambda has a hard timeout of 5 minutes. If you sync job takes too long, you'll need to break it in smaller chunks.

Comment: Great solution! But as you said, the problem is with Lambda timing out in 5 mins. I had problems copying larger files within S3 due to this. I guess, it could be lowered to 100 or so if the file sizes are bigger.

Comment: Exactly, you'll need to experiment with different batch sizes to keep the syncing under 5 minutes, with a good margin to minimize chances of timing out. You could also replace the second Lambda function by an EC2 server with a script that reads from SQS and syncs the data (without a timeout limit). This script could be triggered every 30 minutes, for example, with a local CRON job.

Comment: Interesting idea. Can this work when the source files are outside of the AWS? My logs are on an unmanaged server and wouldn't be visible to Lambda or S3. 

Would it be an analogous process to set up a filesystem-level check for new files on the log host, which are then regularly sent via something (SQS, Kinesis) to S3?

Comment: 1) Pull files from the external server: 1.1) setup a web server (e.g. Apache) to handle HTTP requests; 1.2) a Lambda function or an EC2 server would send an HTTP request every X minutes/hours; 1.3) the external server would respond with the files; 1.4) Lambda/EC2 would sync the files directly to EMR/Hive or save to S3 for later sync. -- OR -- (...)

Comment: (...) -- OR -- 2) Push from external server into AWS (basically the same process, but reversed): 2.1) A script is triggered by a CRON job in the external server; 2.2) this script sends an HTTP request with new log files to an EC2 server or a Lambda function (use [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html) to expose Lambda to HTTP requests); 2.3) EC2/Lambda would sync the files directly to EMR/Hive or save to S3 for later sync.

Comment: (...) -- OR -- 3) Push from external server into AWS S3 using boto library: 3.1) create a Python script in the external server that uses (Boto3 S3)[http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html] library to sync the files automatically into an S3 bucket; 3.2) This script could be triggered by a CRON job every X minutes/hours in the external server. 3.3) Then you can have the Lambda functions to work on new files sync'ed on S3, as I described in my answer above.

Comment: Option 3 looks the most promising, since I wouldn't need to provision a new HTTP server/Lambda function. However, it does put load on the log server, so I'll need to play around with the sync interval to avoid resource contention. Thanks for all the options! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the bucket up to log HTTP requests to a separate bucket, then parse the log to look for newly created files and their paths. One troublespot, as well as PUT requests, you have to look for the multipart upload ops which are a sequence of POSTs. Best to log for a few days to see what gets created before putting any effort in to this approach